# imagemagik equivalent command to setting Photoshop image mode to RGB Color & 8bit/Channel

Tags: php, imagemagick

Please accept my apologies if this question is a duplicate - I have spent several hours trawling the internet for the answer - part of the issue is I am uncertain if -colorspace and -depth are all I need to acheive my goal.

Essentially we have a process which needs to ensure that all files sent to it have some standard consitencies. Currently the file is opened in Photoshop, the image mode is set to RGB Color and 8 Bits/Channel and any empty transparent parts of the PNG are trimmed.

I am now attempting to do this programatically to save time.

```
convert TEST-16BIT.png -depth 8 TEST-8BIT-DEPTH.png
```

This successfully changes the file to 8bit from 16bit with no noticeable changes in the files appearance.

[image]

However using -colorspace is causing the grey to turn black ragardless or wether the image mode was already RGB or CMYK. From the research I've done - this appears to be what I should be using?

[image]

So my question is have I misunderstood the nature of colourspace and this isn't the correct use for it - or do I infact need to use with some additional options that I havn't thought of?

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

All commands have been run using **ImageMagick 6.9.11**

Comment: Please post an original input, not a screen snap. If the input is CMYK. You should use profiles to change colorspace.

Comment: @fmw42 OK great thank you for your reply - is there a list anywhere of the profiles that imagemagick accepts? The documentation on Imagemagick doesn't seem to relaborate on what you can/cannot use?

Comment: You should be able to use any .icc or .icm profiles. The profiles you need to use depend upon whether the input has a profile or not. If it does then you need only the desired output profile (such as sRGB.icc). If there is no input profile and you have a CMYK input, then you need two profiles. The first to define the input (such as USWebCoatedSWOP.icc) and the second the desired output profile (such as sRGB.icc). See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#profiles